# How to suppress compiler warning

Tags: ios, swift3, llvm-clang

this code:

```
guard let isNotNil = anOptional
        else {
            #if DEBUG
                fatalError()
            #endif
            return false
    }
```

gives a compiler warning when in debug mode on `return false`:

> Will never been executed

Which is right but by intention.

How can I suppress this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an else statement:

```
guard let isNotNil = anOptional
        else {
            #if DEBUG
                fatalError()
            #else
                return false
            #endif

}
```

You can also go to the project or the target build settings and disable the warning for unreachable code.

Comment: Is it also possible to suppress a warning only in this place, whithin code?